# How to use Google assistant without dialog flow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I create an action on google assistant and I create a webhook but I need to use my NLP engine not dialog flow NLP, is there a way to do that?

And is there any API endpoint for google assistant?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/). With that SDK you can use your own NLP and generate the responses you like.

Comment: I am trying to follow up with this link [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/create-a-project) but the documentation is different from the action console

Comment: Yep that is right, because in the actions console is just the documentation for the dialogflow hooks linked. Out of my perspective not many people use actions on google without dialogflow.

Answer (score 1):

I Solve it, using **gactions CLI** [gactions CLI Website](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) and follow up the Action SDK Documentation.